# The current path,didn't match any of these

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I have this in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path("product/<str:title>/<slug:pname>/<uuid:puid>",views.viewProduct),
]
```

But when I try to click on the url. I got this error.

```
The current path, product/amazon/home-secure-snake-shield-natural-snake-r/B0882NKXW7, didn't match any of these.
```

Here I just want the puid but to match the pattern of URL I added str:title and str:pname

I don't want the title and pname. But my URL patern is like this-

```
product/store_name/product_name_slug/product_id
```

Comment: `B0882NKXW7` is not a valid `uuid`, an `uuid` is for example `2707820f-5182-407d-9c07-ff7845807d4c`.

Comment: Then how to get this B0882NKXW7 ?

Comment: well the question is where your `B0882NKXW7` comes from? It looks like this is somehow encoded in the template/view/... You can use `<str:puid>` to accept the `B088...`.

Comment: Thanks. I use str:puid and it works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replace the URL path

```
urlpatterns = [
path("product/<str:title>/<slug:pname>/<str:puid>",views.viewProduct),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `B0882NKXW7` is not a valid format for a [*UUID* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). Indeed, a UUID is typically represented as 16 octets. For example `2707820f-5182-407d-9c07-ff7845807d4c` is a UUID.

You can either [define your own path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) to accept your product id, or you can make use of `str:`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/<str:title>/<slug:pname>/<str:puid>', views.viewProduct),
]
```